# Deploying flask including created venv by manipulating pyvenv.cfg

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm new to python and venv and I think I'm misunderstanding the design of venv here.

I've created a flask project with python 3.8 locally(win 10) and planned to deploy to a server(windows server 2016) that **DOES NOT** have python 3.8 installed.

I've created virtual environment locally with below cmd:

```
python -m venv env
```

After checking the pyvenv.cfg file, the home key shows:

```
home = local\absolute\path\to\python\used\to\create\venv
```

As expected, I copied the whole project folder to the server and activate the venv returns me with

```
no python at local\absolute\path\to\python\used\to\create\venv
```

So I changed the pyvenv.cfg home key to the python interpreter in the deploy venv

```
home = deploy\absolute\path\to\Scripts\dir\in\venv
```

Yet if I run activate.bat and start my flask project, the process just hanged there and flask isn't responding.

Besides, If I simply run activate.bat and type in python, it just hangs there and not even the python version is showing up. My problems are:

1. Is manually changing the home key in pyvenv.cfg to the interpreter included in the venv a good practice to get the project running when target python version is not installed?

- If yes, what are the possible reasons causing my process to halt? I assume that everything needed to run python are included in the venv.
- If not, why doing so causes the process to halt?
- Or should I get python 3.8 installed instead? Since i found some saying the only way to get it running is through pyinstaller if python is not installed, but wrapping whole flask app to an exe doesn't seem practical

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!